# Spring Batch app in Kubernetes running linux commands on server

Tags: linux, spring-boot, shell, kubernetes, spring-batch

Looking for any suggestions on possible solutions for running a Spring Batch app deployed in Kubernetes to access directories on a server, run commands, etc.

This app has two Jobs & uses a host of Tasklets to perform work using linux commands on the server.  The Tasklets replace the existing script files.

Job A : take the daily file located in a directory on the server, move the file between different directories(prep the file), finally encrypt the file on the server & SFTP the file to a vendor.

Job B : Retrieve an acknowledgment file from the vendor : when the ack file is available from the vendor, we retrieve the file via SFTP, move it around some directories on the server.

Seems to be a fairly straight forward process but how an application in Kubernetes accesses directories & runs commands on a server has not been so straight forward based on the research we have done.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how an application in Kubernetes accesses directories & runs commands on a server

- Spring Batch provides the [SystemCommandTasklet](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html) that you can use to run commands from within your jobs.
- In regard to file access, you can use a kubernetes persistent volume and make your batch app claim access to it with a [persistent volume claim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/)